# Can't connect to WAMP server through local network

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wamp

I'm trying to connect using my VB.NET app to a WAMP server that is located on another PC (on local network), but I'm getting an error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

That happens just if I'm trying to connect via my app (if I type on local PC in browser xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpmyadmin it works, and on server machine it works via browser and via app).

```
Dim build As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
build.Server = "192.168.1.4"
build.Database = "gydytojo asistentas_new"
build.UserID = "root"
build.Password = ""
build.Port = "3306"
build.CharacterSet = "utf8"
build.MaximumPoolSize = "1000"
Return build.ConnectionString`
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add your program's relevant code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: i just find out same issue there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101208/wamp-and-vb-net-unable-to-connect-to-mysql-host

Comment: Are you sure this is no network issue? Did you try disabling firewall (on your pc and on remote). In most cases database servers are not accesible over the net - so this would make your server vulnerable - but maybe the solution for you. Furthermore I am not sure if you can use such a database name - perhaps put it in [ ]

Comment: Thank you . adding exception in firewall helped

Comment: If my answer was of any help for you - please consider voting it up and/or selecting it as best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is **no network issue**? Did you try **disabling firewall** (on your pc and/or on remote). In most cases database servers are not accesible over the net - so this would make your server vulnerable - but maybe the solution for you.

You may have a look at this question on **security.stackExchange.com** discussing this topic.

> *[What is the best practice for placing DataBase servers in secure network topologies](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8861/what-is-the-best-practice-for-placing-database-servers-in-secure-network-topolog)*